# How to take more than one input from users in HTML form and search in MySql database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, relational-database

I am trying to make a web form that take multiple ids and search that ids in MySql database and then return that row in table.

**PHP script**

```
<form method="post" name="display" action="multi.php" />
Enter the name you like to display the data from MySQL:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" multiple />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</html>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root123") or die("Connection  Failed");
mysql_select_db("myDB")or die("Connection Failed");
$name = array();
 foreach ($_POST as $name)
   {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM check_12 where name = '$name'";
   }

  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  echo '<tr>

            <td>'.$line['ID'].'</td>
            <td>'.$line['Name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$line['Email Id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$line['Address'].'</td>
            <td>'.$line['Phone number'].'</td>
            <td>'.$line['Remark'].'</td>

        </tr>';
```

Comment: ever heard of autocomplete field?

Comment: SQL injection waiting to happen. Please do not use mysql functions. Switch to PDO or MYSQLI and use prepared statements.

Comment: hmm seems like you are new to PHP ,just a note keep the PHP code that works on the back end in a separate PHP file. also as @Akin has said you should not use `mysql` as it is deprecated instead use `mysqli` and you will have to also perform SQL injection checks or switch to PDO statements\

Comment: For a web form that takes multiple IDs, simply use a <select multiple> rather than an <input>. But am I seeing correctly that you are echoing HTML _after_ the </html> end tag? Why?

Comment: Also if you are executing both html and php on the same page, why do you have an action attribute in your html form?

Comment: Thanks a lot Akin, Immortal Dude and Mr Lister. But can you make a correction in my php script file that i have attached as you rightly said i am new to PHP so not able to understand the suggestions very well.